# VBA Access assign results of SP to textbox or display in table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have this code which seems to work, it does not give me any errors. It's just suppose to read a SP stored on SQL Server. But where does the result go? And how to I display the results in a table or assign it to a textbox in Access.
(Im new to VBA and Access)

```
Sub modSQL_ConnadObjectAndStoredProcedure()
'example of a command object using input and output parameter
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
Dim txtConnectionString As String
txtConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MYSERVER; " & _
"Initial Catalog=DisaggregatedPatronage;Integrated Security=SSPI"
conn.ConnectionString = txtConnectionString
cmd.CommandText = "usp_CountOrdersByDate2"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn.ConnectionString
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("ReturnValue", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
cmd.Parameters.Append param
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("Thedate", adDBDate, adParamInput, _
, "16 August 1996")
cmd.Parameters.Append param
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("OrderCount", adInteger, adParamOutput)
cmd.Parameters.Append param
For Each param In cmd.Parameters
Debug.Print param.name, param.Value
Next
cmd.Execute
Debug.Print cmd.Parameters("OrderCount")
Debug.Print cmd.Parameters("ReturnValue")
Set cmd = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is not going to produce the results that I think you are looking for. That code will execute a stored procedure, but will not show you any results from that.  Can you share what is in the SP named 'usp_CountOrdersByDate2'?

The 'Debug.print' you have inside the 'For' loop is just going to loop through the parameters for that SP, showing the name and value. I hope you know that the Debug.print results are sent to the 'Immediate' window.

The two Debug.print's after the Execute are just showing the values of the parameters you submitted earlier.  If you are trying to get the results of some query, you need a different approach. Makes a world of difference as to what the stored procedure does.